# Adding a plugin's meta box to my own plugin's custom post type screen

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for a client that registers a custom post type. The client uses a separate plugin that registers a meta box to the post edit screen, which I believe allows the author to associate some metadata to the current post.

This meta box is not available on my custom post type's screen. For reference, here's my call to `register_post_type()`:

```
register_post_type('company_gallery', [
    'labels' => [
        'name' => __('Galleries'),
        'singular_name' => __('Gallery')
    ],

    // This will register the class that gives us multiple panels
    'register_meta_box_cb' => [$box, 'addMetaBox'],

    // Rules pertaining to URL rewrites
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => '/',
        'with_front' => false
    ],

    // General arguments (see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)
    'supports' => ['title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'],
    'taxonomies' => ['category', 'post_tag'],
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'query_var' => false
]);
```

Is there something I've misunderstood and done wrong, or is there a way I can make the plugins interoperable?

Comment: Due to the nature of the [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) function, the plugin that registers the metabox should add the custom post type as additional page or you create the same metabox to your post type using the [`add_meta_boxes_{post-type}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) hook.

Comment: @Mithc I was hoping to avoid recreating the meta box, since this plugin's API is not public nor guaranteed to remain backwards compatible. Oh well, I guess. Thanks for replying! :)